# Issue with Surf Oauth as a Third-Party Key Manager WSO2

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am trying to implement Surf OAuth as third party key manager in WSO2 API Manager.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager

But after deploying it to tomcat, none of the buttons work, they return nothing. In Chrome developer tools, source option I have seen that it misses one of the template folder. Kindly see the image,

[image: Surf OAuth Image]

How do I make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the latest source code for Surf Oauth Server from [here](https://github.com/OAuth-Apis/apis). It seems the Surf Oauth WAR has customization. You don't need to depend on the Surf OAuth Server provided in the documentation.

You can clone the source code from above github repo and build it. You can start the Surf Oauth Server in following way. It's a Jetty project.

```
cd apis-authorization-server-war
mvn jetty:run
```

Comment: Thanks Abimaran, I tried what you have said, but it also does not work. The war deploys but doesn't start at all.
If possible can you provide me a working .war?